# How can I import jetty source code into eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

I'm trying to import the jetty source code into eclipse.

I went to:

```
Import -> General | Existing projects into workspace
```

then browsed to the folder that has all the jetty related projects:

[image]

Then it doesn't seem to pick up any of the individual projects, the projects pane is empty.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you want to make changes to Jetty? If you just want to browse the source attaching a source jar file would be easier.

Comment: Because the source code directory is not a eclipse project folder.  A eclipse project folder must contains this two file: '.classpath' and '.project' . If this project has maven support, you can use maven to create a Eclipse project.

Comment: @donnior can you provide some steps to do that?   Thilo I want to both view the source and run in debug mode so I can trace through and learn the inner workings of it.

Comment: @Blankman If the source code project has maven support, you can use `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to create a Eclipse project. For more information you can reference http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/

Comment: @Blankman I've checked jetty source code found it already have maven support. So you can use `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to create the Eclipse project then you can import it using 'Import -> Existing projects into workspace'

Comment: You don't need to import Jetty as a project in order to get what you're asking for. You can add the jetty jars (with source attached) to your own project and run/view/debug from there. Unless you actually want to make changes to the Jetty code, an eclipse project is an unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 4):

Jetty is a Maven project.

You'll want to do the following ...

1. Install the m2e plugin.

   - [menu] Help > Eclipse Marketplace
   - Search for "m2e"
   - Install "Maven Integration for Eclipse"
2. Checkout the source code for jetty somewhere onto your disk (or just unpack the source zip file)
3. Import the maven projects

   - [menu] File > Import
   - [tree] Maven > Existing Maven Projects
   - [Next button]
   - Browse to the top folder of the jetty source tree.
   - Hit Next / Finish to then import all of jetty into eclipse.
4. Wait for Eclipse + M2E to settle down with its compilation and project setup.